# Find largest product of longest subsequence between min and max

Tags: code-golf, sequence

## **Input:**

A non-empty sequence of integers greater than zero, the length of which is greater than 1.

## **Output:**

The largest product of all elements of the longest subsequence between the minimum and maximum elements of sequence including themselves.

### Note:

Because the minimum and maximum elements can be repeated, then to a definite answer necessary to find the longest possible subsequence, at one end of which is a minimum and at the other end maximum elements of the sequence. If there is multiple longest subsequences then choose subsequence with largest product.

## Examples:

### 1st example:

Input: `[5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 7, 5]`

Output: `42`

Explanation:
`min == 1`, `max == 7`. There is 2 possible subsequences with min and max on ends: `[1, 2, 2, 7]` and  `[7, 3, 2, 1]`. Their length is equal, so comparing products: `7*3*2*1 == 42` and `1*2*2*7 == 28`. Because `42 >= 28`, answer: `42`.

### 2nd example:

Input: `[1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1]`

Output: `32`

Explanation: 
`min == 1`, `max == 4`. 2 subsequences: `[1, 2, 2, 2, 4]` and `[4, 3, 3, 1]`. Length of `[1, 2, 2, 2, 4]` is greater than length of `[4, 3, 3, 1]`. product: `1*2*2*2*4 == 32` => answer is `32`.

### 3d example:

Input: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1]`

Output: `36`

Short explanation:
`min == 1`, `max == 4`. 2 subsequences: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[4, 3, 3, 1]`. `1*2*3*4 == 24`, `4*3*3*1 == 36`, `36 >= 24` => answer is `36`.

### 4th example:

Input: `[2, 2, 2]`

Output: `8`

Explanation: 
`min == 2`, `max == 2`. 2 different subsequences: `[2, 2]` and `[2, 2, 2]`. Length of `[2, 2, 2]` is greater than length of `[2, 2]`. product: `2*2*2 == 8` => answer is `8`.

### More *(random)* examples:

```
>>>[7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 6, 2, 5, 4, 3]
288
>>>[3, 3, 8, 9, 1, 7, 7, 2, 2, 4]
9
>>>[3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1, 8, 8, 7, 9]
4032
>>>[7, 4, 2, 8, 8, 3, 9, 9, 5, 6]
31104
```

## Check your solution:

Here is Python 3 lambda *(788 bytes)*, which satisfies the requirement of the task:

```
lambda O: __import__('functools').reduce(__import__('operator').mul,O[[[slice(O.index(max(O)),len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(min(O))+1),slice(O.index(min(O)),(len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(max(O)))+1)][__import__('functools').reduce(__import__('operator').mul,O[O.index(min(O)):(len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(max(O)))+1],1)>=__import__('functools').reduce(__import__('operator').mul,O[O.index(max(O)):len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(min(O))+1],1)],slice(O.index(min(O)),(len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(max(O)))+1),slice(O.index(max(O)),len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(min(O))+1)][(len(range(O.index(min(O)),(len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(max(O)))+1))>len(range(O.index(max(O)),len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(min(O))+1)))-(len(range(O.index(min(O)),(len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(max(O)))+1))<len(range(O.index(max(O)),len(O)-1-O[::-1].index(min(O))+1)))]],1)
```

## Winner:

Shortest solution will win. All programming languages accepted.

*P.S.: I will be happy to the explanations of your solutions*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
.ịạ/;L;P
ẆÇ€ṀṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@6/3cHf3w10L9a19rAO4Hu5qO9z@qGnNw50ND3eu@g9mR/7/H83FGW2qo2Cuo2Cso2Cko2AIJo3AIqaxOkBZuAgQmYCVAZEhkpQxhjhUPZhtDlNjpqNgASaBXFOIFrACiEaglCXYdnMwgloHU2AE1gjRZQhWbAFWZgmzwgSsBiJuDDbKEqzeLJYrFgA)

#### How it works

```
ẆÇ€ṀṪ     Main link. Argument: A (array)

Ẇ         Window; generate all substrings of A.
 Ç€       Map the helper link over the substrings.
   Ṁ      Take the maximum.
    Ṫ     Tail; select the last element.


.ịạ/;L;P  Helper link. Argument: S (array / substring)

.ị        At-index 0.5; select the last and first element of S.
  ạ/      Reduce by absolute difference.
    ;L    Append the length of S.
      ;P  Append the product of S.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
NMpMr/€LÐṀịµP€Ṁ
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Tk1wTXIv4oKsTMOQ4bmA4buLwrVQ4oKs4bmA&input=&args=WzcsNiwxLDIsMiw3XQ)**

#### How?

```
NMpMr/€LÐṀịµP€Ṁ - Main link: list of integers, L
           µ    - links to the left as a monadic chain with argument L
N               - negate elements of L
 M              - indexes of maximal elements (i.e. indexes of minimal elements of L)
   M            - indexes of maximal elements of L
  p             - Cartesian product of the min and max indexes
     /€         - reduce each list (all of which are pairs) with the dyad:
    r           -     range(a,b)  (note if a>b this is [a,a-1,...,b])
        ÐṀ      - filter keeping those with maximal
       L        -     length
          ị     - index into L (vectorises)   (get the values)
            P€  - product of a list for €ach
              Ṁ - maximum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org/), 108 bytes

```
{max ([*] $_ for .[.grep(+.max(+*)) with (for .min,.max,.max,.min {.first($^a,:k).. .first($^b,:k,:end)})])}
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 146 bytes

```
z=apply(expand.grid(which(max(x<-scan())==x),which(min(x)==x)),1,function(y)c(prod(x[y[1]:y[2]]),abs(diff(y))));max(z[1,which(z[2,]==max(z[2,]))])
```

Tricky challenge because of the length requirement. Also annoying because the would-be useful builtin `which.max` only returns the index of the first maximum it encounters, forcing me to use `which(max(x)==x)` instead... 3 times. Ohwell...

#### Readable:

```
x <- scan()

maxs <- which(max(x)==x)
mins <- which(min(x)==x)
q <- expand.grid(maxs,mins)
z <- apply(q,1,function(y){
  c(prod(x[y[1]:y[2]]), abs(diff(y)))
  })

max(z[1, which(z[2, ]==max(z[2, ]))])
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>189</s> <s>173</s> 166 bytes

```php
<?foreach($a=$_GET[a]as$p=>$b)foreach($a as$q=>$c)$b>min($a)|$c<max($a)?:$r[$d=abs($p-$q)+1]=array_product(array_slice($a,min($p,$q),$d));ksort($r);echo max(end($r));
```

similarly lazy but 33 bytes shorter (had to add 10 bytes to turn the snippet into a program):

1. Loop `$p/$b` and `$q/$c` through the array; if `$b==min` and `$c==max`,
   add product of the sub-sequence to `$r[sub-sequence length]`
2. Sort `$r` by keys.
3. Print the max value of the last element.

Call in browser with array as GET parameter `a`.
Example: `script.php?a[]=5&a[]=7&a[]=3&a[]=2&a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=2&a[]=7&a[]=5`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 122 bytes

```
(g=#;Sort[{#.{-1,1},Times@@Take[g,#]}&/@Sort/@Join@@Outer[List,Sequence@@(Union@@Position[g,#@g]&/@{Max,Min})]][[-1,-1]])&
```

Surprised how long this turned out to be. First generates the Cartesian product of the appearances of the minima and maxima (as per [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103751/56178)), then computes the lengths of those runs and their products, and selects the appropriate one by taking the last element of the sorted results.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 187 bytes

```js
f=
(l,M=Math,a=M.min(...l),z=M.max(...l),r=(m,n)=>[eval(l.slice(b=l.indexOf(m),c=l.lastIndexOf(n)+1).join`*`),M.abs(b-c)])=>(u=r(a,z),v=r(z,a),u[1]>v[1]?u[0]:v[1]>u[1]?v[0]:M.max(v[0],u[0]))


console.log([
  [5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 7, 5],
  [1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1],
  [2, 2, 2],
  [7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 6, 2, 5, 4, 3],
  [3, 3, 8, 9, 1, 7, 7, 2, 2, 4],
  [3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1, 8, 8, 7, 9],
  [7, 4, 2, 8, 8, 3, 9, 9, 5, 6]
].map(a=>`[${a}] => ${f(a)}`).join`
`)
```